# Getting Deadlock while updating in bulk in django

Tags: django, postgresql, deadlock

Getting Deadlock while updating transactions in bulk using django function `bulk_update` in with `transaction.atomic()`?
can someone help me here?

> Error :- deadlock detected DETAIL:  Process "abc" waits for ShareLock
>   on transaction "xyz"; blocked by process "qaz". Process "tgb" waits
>   for ShareLock on transaction "rfvb"; blocked by process "wsx".

getting this error.

postgresql database.

Comment: what db are you using ?

Comment: @NakulNarayanan Based on the error message, it's probably PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please show us some of the code, too.